# A tag not working in framework 7

Tags: javascript, html-framework-7

I'm working on framework7.

```
<a href="page1" class="link">link1</a>
```

Not working
Here is my route code

```
Var app = new Framework ({
     Route:[
        {Path:'page1',url:'page/page1.html'}]});
```

Answer (score 0):

change this line to

```
<a href="/page1/" class="link">link1</a>
```

In app.js

```
// Dom7
var $ = Dom7;


// Init App
var app = new Framework7({
  root: '#app',
  routes:  [
  // Index page
  {
    path: '/',
    url: './index.html',
    name: 'home',
  },
  // About page
  {
    path: '/page1/',
    url: './page/page1.html',
    name: 'about',
  }],
  vi: {
    placementId: 'pltd4o7ibb9rc653x14',
  },
});
```

path in the routes must be within like /pagename/ this is same you provide in href of anchor tag

Comment: Yes pages/page1.html

Comment: pages/page1.html should be ./pages/page1.html if this still dont work then add your app.js code in question